# Imprimir con Win 8.1 sin abrir el print preview

Tags: c#, windows

Quisiera saber si alguien ha tenido oportunidad de investigar como hacer para imprimir imágenes seleccionándolas desde el disco duro y que sin abrir la imagen la imprima, usando c#.

Comment: cuando dice Win8.1 se trata de un desarrollo ModerUI para el store ? o es un desarrollo winforms simple que ejecuta sobre Win8.1

Comment: Si win 8.1 store with c# and xaml.
Tengo un ejemplo pero siempre abre el print preview y el cliente quiere que se imprima directo a la impresora sin abrir el archivo.

Answer (score 1):

En Windows 8 para adelante, existen dos tipos de aplicaciones que se pueden ejecutar:

1. Aplicaciones ModernUI que están diseñadas para ser publicadas en el Store de Windows y desde donde se instalarán.
2. Aplicaciones digamosle tradicionales, que no requieren ser publicadas en el Store y se pueden ejecutar simplemente con un doble click.

Si se trata de este segundo caso, entonces debes utilizar la clase PrintDocument. Esta clase es la que se encarga de enviar el contenido que tu indiques (texto, imágenes, etc) a la impresora que indiques.

Existe un cuadro de diálogo para seleccionar impresora y otro para configurar parámetros que puedes invocar opcionalmente desde tu aplicación, pero no es obligatorio...

El siguiente es un código de muestra para efectuar la tarea...

```
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Printing;

    namespace PrinterTest
    {
      class Program
      {
           static string imageToPrint = @"c:\temp\foto.png";

           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
              PrintDocument prn = new PrintDocument();
              prn.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"; //Debes indicar a qué impresora se enviará el documento.
              //Con Printdocument se genera el contenido página a página, para esto se dispara un evento PrintPage
              prn.PrintPage+=prn_PrintPage; //Acá indicamos el Event Handler que se invocará para generar el contenido de cada página.
              prn.Print();
           }

          private static void prn_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
          {
              Image img = Image.FromFile(imageToPrint);
              //El método DrawImage envía una imagen a impresión.
              e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 10,10,img.Width,img.Height);
              //Si esta es la última página, HasMorePages es False.
              e.HasMorePages = false;
          }
        }
     }
```

Todavía es necesario verificar temas de escalado de la imagen, si por ejemplo quieres que ocupe toda la página, pero eso ya no es tan complejo.

En el caso de aplicaciones ModernUI, me parece que no es factible hacerlo de acuerdo a la siguiente información.

[Printing from Windows app directly without bringing Print Dialog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2d7c00f0-702b-47f5-8813-20e10b52d13a/uwpprinting-from-windows-app-directly-without-bringing-print-dialog?forum=wpdevelop)

Espero la información te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación. Realmente es Win app, asi que te agradezco el link. Creo que lo voy a analizar a ver que tan factible es usarlo.